# Using separate text and value with jqGrid MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm currently using MVC to set up jqGrid. I'm trying to make a table for user roles. One column should have the user, one column should have the role. Not too complicated. However, currently, they're formatted as strings, and looking at long ID strings isn't very useful. So I want the Ids formatted as the username and role name they correspond to, but I still want the underlying value to be the UserId and RoleId so it's easy to edit and make changes. Currently, I have it so when you go to edit them, a dropdown box will show up that formats the UserId as a UserName while retaining the value of UserId, but I don't know how to make it show like that when I'm not editing...

Here's the code for the dropdown box.

```
    private void SetUpUserNameColumn(JQGrid userRoleGrid)
    {
        // setup the grid search criteria for the columns
        JQGridColumn userIdColumn = userRoleGrid.Columns.Find(c => c.DataField == "UserId");
        userIdColumn.Editable = true;
        userIdColumn.EditType = EditType.DropDown;

        // Populate the search dropdown only on initial request, in order to optimize performance
        if (userRoleGrid.AjaxCallBackMode == AjaxCallBackMode.RequestData)
        {
            var db = new ApplicationDbContext();
            var editList = from user in db.Users
                           select new SelectListItem
                           {
                               Text = user.UserName,
                               Value = user.UserId
                           };

            userIdColumn.EditList = editList.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution we are using is to add a CustomFormatter to that column. Here is the relevant code for that.

1. When creating your Grid in the code behind you'll want to add a CustomFormatter like below.

   ```
   var jqGrid = new JQGrid 
   {
       Columns = 
       { 
           new JQGridColumn
           { 
               HeaderText = "Role"
             , DataField  = "RoleId"
             , Formatter  = new CustomFormatter { FormatterFunction = "RoleFormatter" }
           }
       }
   };
   ```
2. Then you'll need to write the RoleFormatter function in JS and add it to your view.

   ```
   <script>
       function RoleFormatter(cellValue, options, rowObject) {

           if(cellValue == '1') return 'Admin'
           if(cellValue == '2') return 'Client'
           if(cellValue == '3') return 'Lucky'

           return cellValue;
       }
   </script>
   ```

And that is it. The column displays the Formatter return value while actually being set to the RoleId.